# Generating a minimal set of vertices from a spline/curve

Tags: algorithm, polygon, computational-geometry, spline

In my project, I represent geometry using splines. For physics and rendering I preprocess the splines and convert them into lines, and later polygons, by sampling the splines at a regular interval. However, I want to reduce the number of vertices/lines by ignoring samples that are already well enough represented by a line.

Coming up short when searching, I was wondering if there are any traditional techniques to convert a curve to a set of vertices while reducing the resulting error.

EDIT: To clarify, the result I want to end up with is a number of vertices/line segments that best represent the spline with the fewest amount of vertices/line segments. I'm not sure how to define what "best represent the spline" really means, but the goal is to make it as hard as possible to distinguish the difference between the spline and the approximation.

Comment: The "traditional" technique I knew was about doing an optimization minimizing the max distance.

Comment: Are there any constraints or additional useful properties that could be of assistance? For example: if the points can be determined by some functions x(t) and y(t) where t is vertices' index (so the 1st vertex would be (x(0), y(0)) ) it would give us a little more to work with.

Comment: @Nate, my embarrassingly low math skills makes me avoid trying to explain the problem in those terms as I expect it to confuse more than it would help.

However, if the spline is s(0 -> 1) and I sample s(0.01), s(0.02), s(0.03), ..., s(1) to get xy[0], xy[1], xy[2], ..., xy[100]. (In this case xy is a 2d vertex, but I don't expect the problem to be differnet in 3d). Then I want to find a set of s(t0), s(t1), s(t2), ..., s(tn) from where a linear interpolation will match s(0 -> 1) up to a specified amount of "error".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by recursively refining part which is not near segment between part ends.

If we have curve (spline) `C:[0,1]->R^n`. Than first approximation is segment `S` between curve end points `[C(0), C(1)]`. Take point `C(0.5)` and check how far is it from segment `S`. If it is far than we have to take it in discretization, if not than `S` is good approximation. If `C(0.5)` is far, than next approximation is polyline `[C(0), C(0.5), C(1)]`, and we make same procedure with parts `[C(0), C(0.5)]` and `[C(0.5), C(1)]`.

If you are using polynomial spline of order >= 3 (e.g. cubic spline) than it can have inflection point(s). In that case it is possible that curve point on half can 'fall' right on segment, but curve around to be far from segment. In that case it is good to check one more level of sub-parts.

Comment: Hmm, that's really clever. It's especially nice since it doesn't require me to sample a ton of points on the curve that would be discarded anyway.

Comment: It simple and nice. An algorithm is standard one, but I couldn't find a description. I know that I read about it on Wikipedia.

Comment: If you can represent your spline using Bezier curves (this is possible from a cubic spline), then the hull property allows you to use the recursive subdivision approach with an absolute guarantee on the approximation, even in presence of inflection points.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely based on my own intuition, so I'm not sure if it coincides AT ALL with best practices. I do have a mathematics degree, so hopefully it's not too far off. I'll have you note that the computation involved may outstrip performance gains granted by not using as many vertices if the spline needs to be recalculated frequently.

Let's say the vertices are in an array like [v(0), v(1), v(2),..., v(n)] where each v(i) is something like (x, y). By iterating over the vertices starting at v(1) and ending at v(n-1), we can compare a point with its neighbors in order to tell whether or not to discard it. Note that we ignore v(0) and v(n) for two reasons: (I assume) we don't want to remove our endpoints, and also v(0) and v(n) are missing a neighbor that we would need in order to set up our calculation. I can think of a couple possibilities here that might warrant examination, but one in particular seems (in my head) to be the best answer...

Consider the case where we're deciding whether or not to remove v(i) from the vertex array. We could examine the Cartesian distance between v(i) and its neighbors, and remove the point if both are below some threshold value T. For example if v(i-1) = (x1, y1) and v(i) = (x2, y2) and v(i+1) = (x3, y3), then we evaluate `sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2))<T && sqrt((x3-x2)^2 + (y3-y2)^2))<T`, removing v(i) if the evaluation returns true.

In 3+ dimensions, this would become more complicated - the calculation would be similar, but you would require a method of determining a point's neighbors since they might not lie directly next to the examined point in the vertex array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nate. While this would reduce the number of vertices, it would fail to do so more often where the curve is well represented by the line segments - It would not save vertices during the more curvy parts of the spline to retain the visual fidelity there.